# What's the difference between the terms "Numeral System" and "Number System"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition

I understand that a "Numeral system" is a way to express numbers.

But what is "Number system"?

What's the difference between this two terms?

Comment: it depens on the context that these terms are used (they might even mean the same), do you have a specific example?

Comment: @NikosM. I am reading the theories of "Positional *Numeral* System", and how I can convert a number from one numeral system to another. But the whole time I was subconsciously I reading "Positional *Number* System". Now I am wondering what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numeral system is a way to express numbers.  Base 10 is the most commonly used numeral system, but there is also binary, non-positional notation, and words (e.g "seven million three thousand fifteen").

A number system is a set of numbers as well as certain arithmetic operations we define on them.  Commonly used ones include the integers, the rationals (fractions), the reals, the complex numbers.  In some cases one number system includes another, but not always.

Comment: So by definition, Number system is the set of characters(and certain arithmetic operations) defined by the Numeral System? Can you provide some examples with the second paragraph?

Comment: The second paragraph contains four examples already.  $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$.